# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: conversion failed when converting datetime from character string depending on OS language

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, type-conversion

I'm struggling with DateTime formats and conversion for many days now and after unsuccessful searches, I decided to ask on SO.

I import DateTime values from a .csv file and convert this string value to DateTime using this line of C# code :

```
DateTime.TryParse("24-08-17", new CultureInfo("fr-FR", true), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt);
```

I don't use ParseExact or TryParseExact because the input string format for DateTime values can change.

The problem is :

On my colleague computer which is running the French version of Windows 10 -> everything is fine.

On my computer which is running the en-US version of Windows 10 -> I got a

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : conversion failed when converting
>   datetime from character string

when this DateTime value is used in a SQL parameter executed by this line of VB.Net code :

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

The output SQL statement is the following :

```
select count(*) from xxx where yyy = 212 AND (www <> 2 AND www <> 5) AND zzz = 316882 AND isGgg = 0  and ((date_p >='24-Aug-17 00:00:00' and date_p <='22-Nov-17 00:00:00') or (Date_s >='24-Aug-17 00:00:00' and Date_s <='22-Nov-17 00:00:00'))
```

I could just install the FR language pack for Windows on my computer but I don't consider this as a real solution.

I think the problem could be solved by modifying the DateTime.TryParse line of code, but after trying a lot of things found on the web, I still can't get my problem solved.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?  Dates are not strings and forcing the DB provider to convert will involve culture issues.  Have you tried using date parameters in the SQL?

Comment: Your TryParse is probably fine because that's not where your exception is coming from.  The problem is the format of the date being put into the SQL statement.  When you add the parameter to the query, are you doing ToString() on the DateTime?  By default, that will give the SQL the locale-specific date which it won't understand.  If you pass the DateTime value it *should* convert it correctly.  If not, you could call the version of ToString that takes a format string and explicitly give it the correct format.

Comment: @dwilliss The code shows a query with literals not parameters, but there is no difference between a French DateTime value and a Greek DateTime value.  The NET DBProviders are perfectly capable of passing a DateTime type without converting `ToString`

Comment: when using dates in varchar in sql server, always use a language neutral format, such as 'yyyyMMdd' for example.

Comment: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Comment: @Plutonix.  True.  He said he used a *SQL parameter*, but then the SQL statement would have placeholders, wouldn't it?  So I'm guessing he's not really using query.Parameters.AddWithValue().

Comment: First words: `I'm struggling with DateTime formats` Dates do not have a format, they are a simple value.  Today's date value is `636469056000000000`.  Formats are how that value are displayed to users so they can understand them.  Save Dates as Dates and pass Dates as parameters and life will be sweet.  And do not use `AddWithValue`, use `Add(string, dbtype)`

Comment: I'm using SqlClient.SqlParameter, then use their properties "ParameterName" and "Value" which I fill with my data. Then I call cmd.Parameters.Add(). Am I wrong ? It seems to work when I replace the new CultureInfo (fr-FR, true) by CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in my TryParse line of code. But I don't think that it is a good thing because the input Date I get from the csv file can change at any time, out of my control. For now it's "dd-MM-YY" but for another csv it can be "MM-dd-YY" for which i'll specify the en-US culture.

Comment: The CSV parsing step is a red herring - it will either parse or not parse.  You ought not have to do anything else to it as long as it parses.  But the error indicates that you are **not** passing a date to the DB provider but some sort of string.  You dont show that code hence all the comments.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah you're right. I'm still discovering the code I'm working on, I'm sorry. I found the method which converts the DateTime values I send to string values. It's a simple "ToString()". But I don't have the "right" to change it to "ToString("something")". Is it lost ?

Comment: What is the data type in the DB for this problematic column?

Comment: @Plutonix The data type in the db is "datetime".

Comment: Wonderful.  That means you simply need to pass a `DateTime` variable as a `DateTime` type using DB parameters in a parameterized SQL statement.  That code is not shown (and I am not sure how the query shown factors into anything)  No need to convert anything to string anywhere.

Comment: @Plutonix Okay thanks for your answer, I'll see what I can do. It's a very huge solution, and I'm not authorized to modify every method I want. So I'll discuss about it with my colleague. Thanks again.

Comment: If I would donate 1$ to @Plutonix for every time he uses the (absolutely correct) phrases `Dates do not have a format` and `pass Dates as parameters` he would be a very very rich guy ;)

Comment: So I could modify the way the DateTime values are converted to String from date.ToString() to date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") and it seems to work. Am I right to consider it as a viable solution ? (Because passing the parameter as a DateTime to the SQL statement is not a option ..)

Comment: Passing dates as dates via date parameters is the only ***good*** solution.  Why would you want to pass a string if the datatype for the column is date??? Passing text means the DB provider has to parse it back to datetime which means the prevailing culture is involved.  `"dd/MM/yyyy"` is not a legal format in every culture.

Comment: I 100% agree with you but I don't really have the choice.. I'll discuss about it tomorrow with my colleague but it's possible that we don't have the possibility to change this logic. Everything is passed as string (don't know why)..

Comment: @Plutonix By specifying the culture in the TryParse method call, is there anything I can write in the ToString() method as parameter to be reliable in case I have to deal with passing parameters as string to my sql statements?

Comment: The CSV parsing has nothing to do with it; it sounds like you have that part worked out by knowing the source or culture.  The only culture neutral date format is an ISO8601 form such as "yyyy-MM-dd" but it seems that would break even more things...besides which it is pure overhead and cruft

Comment: Finally, the whole problem is the result of the amateurish decision to use strings in place of dates.  Give the problem to the person whoever made that decision to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is message from SQL server and has nothing to do with parsing. It is necessary to format date properly in a query. I would recomend add `;Current Language=English`to the connection string and use yyyy-mm-dd format for date.

Be carful with `TryParse` because it sometimes changes month and date `TryParseExact` is much more reliable.